# Inser data in mysql

Tags: python, mysql, twitter, tweepy

Hi am new to python and still learning i want to insert some data retrived from twitter into db here is my code

```
    import MySQLdb
    import tweepy
    from tweepy import OAuthHandler
    CONSUMER_KEY = 'A'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'A'
    ACCESS_KEY = 'A'
    ACCESS_SECRET = 'A'
    auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
    api = tweepy.API(auth)
    auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
    user = api.get_user(2883100465)
    print user.id
    print user.screen_name
    print user.name
    print user.profile_image_url
    print user.location
    print user.url
    print user.description
    print user.created_at
    print user.followers_count
    print user.friends_count
    print user.statuses_count
    print user.time_zone
    # Open database connection
    db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","root","EgoNetwork");
    # prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
    cursor = db.cursor()
    # Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
    sql = "INSERT INTO profile(user_id,screen_name,name,profile_image_url,location,url,description,created_at,followers_count,friends_count,statuses_count,time_zone,last_update) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)";
    try:
    cur.execute(sql,("2829756343",user.screen_name,user.name,user.profile_image_url,user.location,user.url,user.description,user.created_at,user.followers_count,user.friends_count,user.statuses_count,user.time_zone,""))
       db.commit()
    except:
       # Rollback in case there is any error
       db.rollback()

    # disconnect from server
    db.close()
```

Here is my error code

```
File "UserProfile.py", line 31
cur.execute(sql,("2829756343",user.screen_name,user.name,user.profile_image_url,user.location,user.url,user.description,user.created_at,user.followers_count,user.friends_count,user.statuses_count,user.time_zone,""))
  ^
```

IndentationError: expected an indented block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indent cur.execute under the try. Instead of

```
try:
cur.execute(sql,("2829756343",user.screen_name,user.name,user.profile_image_url,user.location,user.url,user.description,user.created_at,user.followers_count,user.friends_count,user.statuses_count,user.time_zone,""))
   db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()
```

do this:

```
try:
    cur.execute(sql,("2829756343",user.screen_name,user.name,user.profile_image_url,user.location,user.url,user.description,user.created_at,user.followers_count,user.friends_count,user.statuses_count,user.time_zone,""))
    db.commit()
except:
    # Rollback in case there is any error
    db.rollback()
```

Notice that the error message said, "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Comment: ok thanks that seem to slove the error but no data was inserted

Comment: Because you're catching any exception and not doing anything with it in the except clause, you're not going to see it. Add "raise" after your db.rollback() so you'll see any exception that mysql is throwing.